# Laravel Installation on Apache - index.php issues

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I've been encountering a slew of issues with a fresh install of Laravel on Ubuntu recently but this latest one has me baffled. I was receiving the WSOD with zero errors in `apache/php` logs or laravel logs, despite having debug set to true and error display in PHP enabled. I updated the `index.php` file in public to add a `die("Test");` line just to see if that was at least working.

It was, which was great - Test displayed on the site. However, now it won't go away. I've tried updating the text to something else, completely removing the line, etc., artisan cache-clear, composer cache clear and dump-autoload, and I've cleared out any cached items in the storage folders. I've cleared my personal cache and tried different browsers, also, so it's not a personal cache issue. I also tried restarting apache.

All of my chmod permissions should be correct at this point (bootstrap/cache is 755, all of the storage and subfolders are 755). I have had laravel write to the log for another issue (from CLI - a test I did just to make sure permissions were working) so that shouldn't be the problem.

I have this working perfectly fine in laragon on my local Windows machine but have had nothing but issues getting this guy up and running on this Ubuntu server. I have another prod instance of laravel that never gave me this much trouble, either, on another Ubuntu server (and usually it was just a permissions issue). Really not sure what to do at this point or what information might be useful. Hoping that someone else has run into something similar and can shed some light....

Comment: whats error coming

Comment: @VishalVarshney There's no error at all. That's the most baffling part. It's just not working and public/index.php seems to be stuck in a cached state somewhere/somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem lay with the `opcache` PHP extension. This was enabled on all versions of PHP installed on my prod environment by default and wasn't something I was utilizing on my dev environment. Writing a test to clear opcache resolved this particular problem and I have since disabled the extension, as I was not intending to use it, anyways.

If anyone else runs into this problem and wants to disable, I simply went through WHM Easy Apache 4 and removed the opcache PHP extensions and then edited the php.ini files for all versions of PHP to set any opcache enabled type of flags to 0 (off).

Answer (score 0):

what kind of error show's the file /var/log/apache2/error_log?
what is the content of your laravel file storage/logs/laravel.logs?
how did you configure the vhost? 
did you install laravel with composer?

give us more information please

Comment: As stated, there are no errors in error_log. I even turned on "info" in apache error reporting and there is nothing. I can trigger it to add an error, so it's working. Laravel log file does not contain any errors. I do know it is also working, as I can do some random "laravel command" in SSH and it will show in laravel.log so write permissions are fine. I did install laravel with composer. The lack of data in the logs, despite the fact that they are being written to properly, is one of the reasons I'm so confused.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed.... So, I updated the public/index.php to add the die("Test") line and that seems to be stuck in a cache somewhere. I've tried removing index.php and the server appropriately returns a 404. If I create a totally new index.php file and just put something like echo "Secondary Test", it will return the same cached index.php of die("Test") again. I cannot for the life of me figure out where or how this is being cached.

Comment: what php version is installed on your server?
what is the  .htaccess configuration? 
did you declare some routes for testing some view?

Comment: I have several but was actively using 5.6. I found the issue to the problem, which I'll answer shortly. Apparently the issue was with opcache, which was something I had not enabled on my local dev instance but was enabled by default on my new prod setup.